# Mapping Middle Mouse Button to the End key using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My goal is to map the "Delete" key to the middle mouse, aka my clickable wheel on my mouse. I'm on a Windows 10 machine. Currently, no matter what I do, clicking on the wheel within the Browser and other apps, produces the cross-hair.

I tried:

```
MButton::
Send, {End}
```

also tried

```
WheelDown::
Send, {End}
```

Both did not work. Thoughts?

Comment: See [Mouse remapping](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Comment: @user3419297 I tried "MButton::End" originally, and that did not work. When I click on the middle wheel, I still get the cross-hair.